# How to calculate mean time in dataframe in R

Tags: r

sorry for my english, i'am new in R programming. I have this data in csv

```
DATA1       DATA2
PAPERINO    05:29:29
PAPERINO    04:43:47
PAPERINO    04:43:47
PAPERINO    03:27:46
PIPPO000    00:27:07
PIPPO000    00:27:07
PIPPO000    00:27:07
PIPPO000    00:27:07
PIPPO000    00:26:04
PIPPO000    00:26:04
PIPPO000    00:26:04
BALUBABA    03:02:22
BALUBABA    03:33:29
ZORROBIS    07:56:34
ZORROBIS    07:58:13
ZORROBIS    07:59:06
ZORROBIS    18:17:29
ZORROBIS    18:32:23
ZORROBIS    18:36:50
```

I want group_by DATA1 and calculate the average for each object based on 24 hours.

Result example for ZORROBIS i want two results same this in my excel:

```
ZORROBIS    07:57:58
ZORROBIS    18:28:54
```

I used dplyr and lubridate, but without success.
Thanks to anyone who can help me to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.ITime` to convert to 'Time' object and then take the `mean` after grouping by 'DATA1' and the `hour` of 'DATA2'

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(DATA2 = as.ITime(DATA2)) %>%
   group_by(DATA1, hour = hour(DATA2)) %>%
   summarise(DATA2 = mean(DATA2)) %>%
   select(-hour)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   DATA1 [4]
#  DATA1    DATA2   
#  <chr>    <ITime> 
#1 BALUBABA 03:17:55
#2 PAPERINO 03:27:46
#3 PAPERINO 04:43:47
#4 PAPERINO 05:29:29
#5 PIPPO000 00:26:40
#6 ZORROBIS 07:57:57
#7 ZORROBIS 18:28:54
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
setDT(df1)[, .(DATA2 = mean(as.ITime(DATA2))), by = .(DATA1, hour = hour(as.ITime(DATA2)))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DATA1 = c("PAPERINO", "PAPERINO", "PAPERINO", 
"PAPERINO", "PIPPO000", "PIPPO000", "PIPPO000", "PIPPO000", "PIPPO000", 
"PIPPO000", "PIPPO000", "BALUBABA", "BALUBABA", "ZORROBIS", "ZORROBIS", 
"ZORROBIS", "ZORROBIS", "ZORROBIS", "ZORROBIS"), DATA2 = c("05:29:29", 
"04:43:47", "04:43:47", "03:27:46", "00:27:07", "00:27:07", "00:27:07", 
"00:27:07", "00:26:04", "00:26:04", "00:26:04", "03:02:22", "03:33:29", 
"07:56:34", "07:58:13", "07:59:06", "18:17:29", "18:32:23", "18:36:50"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but when I try to execute the code that you have proposed to me I receive the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Comment: @use I showed reproducble example with `data` in my post.  Not able to reproduce

Comment: I start from a dataframe in csv file df1 <- read.csv2("C://temp//simo//ex1.csv", sep=";")

Comment: @use Here, I am usiing the copy of your data in your post and I don't have access to your C drive

Comment: OK It's correct but when i run the code with your example it's wonderfull but when i read my csv i recive the following error:Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. I do not understand the problem,Anyway thanks 1000 for the help

Comment: @use Try `as.ITime(as.character(DATA2))`

Comment: @use Can you be able. to share a link to the csv file or use `dput` to show the first few rows i.e. `dput(head(df1, 20))`

Comment: I solved, I made this change to the script you sent me, I think it works, tomorrow afternoon I will check better:  mutate(DATA2 = as.ITime(DATA2, format = "%H:%M:%S")) ......thank you very much you have been really very good :-)